# 'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: mongodb

'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
every time i write command on terminal this error is showing

I have set the path of mongodb bin folder into system enviornment but also the error is showing to me give me some advice to solve the error

Comment: There is no executable called `mongo`, at least not in recent versions of MongoDB. If you're looking for the Mongo Shell, that's called `mongosh`.

Comment: the above true for servers >= 6.0